# Errors reading and writing communications packets

Tags: replication, mariadb

After an outage that had us down for 4 days I am attempting to establish replication between 2 of our servers in order to have a "hot" backup available should the need arise.

After dumping all of the databases on the master and creating them on the slave I enabled replication and have had nothing but trouble since. An extract of the log files from the slave and master are included below.

Both servers are sitting on the same VLAN on the same Ethernet segment so there should be, according to our network support folks, zero lag time. The Ethernet MTU on both servers is set to 1500. The `max_allowed_packet` on the master is set to `805306368`.

Both servers are running 10.4.6-MariaDB.

The slave is already almost a day behind and it doesn't look like it is getting any better. I've searched high and low for what the errors in the log mean but none of the suggested solutions have helped or changed the errors in any way.

At this point any suggestions on what else I can try or look at would be appreciated. The `replication_user` referenced in the logs exists on both the master and the slave and has `REPLICATION_CLIENT` and `REPLICATION_SLAVE` authority. I have tried the user with a host of `%`, `10.%` and the name of the slave/master.

The master in this setup is also a slave to another instance but only for a handful of tables in one specific database. That database is NOT replicated to the slave that is having an issue.

From the **SLAVE** log file:

> 2019-07-23 13:54:03 9 [Note] Slave: connected to master
>   'replication_user@10.53.17.154:3306',replication resumed in log
>   'DWR_Master.000002' at position 195396246
>
> 2019-07-23 13:55:33 9 [ERROR] Error reading packet from server: Lost
>   connection to MySQL server during query (server_errno=2013)
>
> 2019-07-23 13:55:33 9 [Note] Slave I/O thread: Failed reading log
>   event, reconnecting to retry, log 'DWR_Master.000002' at position
>   195522037
>
> 2019-07-23 13:55:54 9 [ERROR] Slave I/O: error reconnecting to master
>   'replication_user@10.53.17.154:3306' - retry-time: 60 
>   maximum-retries: 86400  message: Can't connect to MySQL server on
>   '10.53.17.154' (10060 "Unknown error"), Internal MariaDB error code:
>   2003
>
> 2019-07-23 13:57:03 9 [Note] Slave: connected to master
>   'replication_user@10.53.17.154:3306',replication resumed in log
>   'DWR_Master.000002' at position 195522037
>
> 2019-07-23 13:59:21 9 [ERROR] Error reading packet from server: Lost
>   connection to MySQL server during query (server_errno=2013)
>
> 2019-07-23 13:59:21 9 [Note] Slave I/O thread: Failed reading log
>   event, reconnecting to retry, log 'DWR_Master.000002' at position
>   195554351
>
> 2019-07-23 14:01:01 9 [ERROR] Error reading packet from server: Lost
>   connection to MySQL server during query (server_errno=2013)
>
> 2019-07-23 14:01:01 9 [Note] Slave I/O thread: Failed reading log
>   event, reconnecting to retry, log 'DWR_Master.000002' at position
>   195558070
>
> 2019-07-23 14:01:22 9 [ERROR] Slave I/O: error reconnecting to master
>   'replication_user@10.53.17.154:3306' - retry-time: 60 
>   maximum-retries: 86400  message: Can't connect to MySQL server on
>   '10.53.17.154' (10060 "Unknown error"), Internal MariaDB error code:
>   2003
>
> 2019-07-23 14:03:52 9 [Note] Slave: connected to master
>   'replication_user@10.53.17.154:3306',replication resumed in log
>   'DWR_Master.000002' at position 195558070

From the **MASTER** log file:

> 2019-07-23 13:54:03 30885 [Note] Start binlog_dump to
>   slave_server(75), pos(DWR_Master.000002, 195396246)
>
> 2019-07-23 13:54:50 30885 [Warning] Aborted connection 30885 to db:
>   'unconnected' user: 'replication_user' host: 'slave_host_name.com'
>   (Got an error writing communication packets)
>
> 2019-07-23 13:57:03 30966 [Note] Start binlog_dump to
>   slave_server(75), pos(DWR_Master.000002, 195522037)
>
> 2019-07-23 13:58:50 30966 [Warning] Aborted connection 30966 to db:
>   'unconnected' user: 'replication_user' host: 'slave_host_name.com'
>   (Got an error writing communication packets)
>
> 2019-07-23 13:59:30 31071 [Note] Start binlog_dump to
>   slave_server(75), pos(DWR_Master.000002, 195554351)
>
> 2019-07-23 14:00:16 31071 [Warning] Aborted connection 31071 to db:
>   'unconnected' user: 'replication_user' host: 'slave_host_name.com'
>   (Got an error writing communication packets)
>
> 2019-07-23 14:03:52 31217 [Note] Start binlog_dump to
>   slave_server(75), pos(DWR_Master.000002, 195558070)
>
> 2019-07-23 14:04:41 31217 [Warning] Aborted connection 31217 to db:
>   'unconnected' user: 'replication_user' host: 'slave_host_name.com'
>   (Got an error writing communication packets)

Master Status Values:

```
Variable_name               Value
Aborted_clients             455
Aborted_connects            2087
Aborted_connects_preauth        14
Access_denied_errors            4632
Acl_column_grants           0
Acl_database_grants         64
Acl_function_grants         0
Acl_procedure_grants            0
Acl_package_spec_grants         0
Acl_package_body_grants         0
Acl_proxy_users             2
Acl_role_grants             0
Acl_roles               0
Acl_table_grants            2
Acl_users               40
Binlog_commits              49286
Binlog_group_commits            49286
Binlog_group_commit_trigger_count   0
Binlog_group_commit_trigger_lock_wait   0
Binlog_group_commit_trigger_timeout 0
Binlog_snapshot_file            DWR_Master.000002
Binlog_snapshot_position        196890378
Binlog_bytes_written            196969751
Binlog_cache_disk_use           0
Binlog_cache_use            142
Binlog_stmt_cache_disk_use      571
Binlog_stmt_cache_use           49144
Connections             31879
Created_tmp_disk_tables         21949
Created_tmp_files           2324
Created_tmp_tables          170910
Empty_queries               319668
Open_files              3851
Open_table_definitions          1950
Open_tables             2000
Opened_files                177752
Opened_table_definitions        11630
Opened_tables               13882
Opened_views                8587
Queries                 132054966
Questions               1478834
Rows_read               2685456711
Rows_sent               690082934
Rows_tmp_read               490475978
Slave_connections           322
Slave_heartbeat_period          30.000
Slaves_connected            1
Slaves_running              1
Slow_queries                403
Sort_merge_passes           1068
Sort_priority_queue_sorts       5587
Table_locks_immediate           8709091
Table_locks_waited          88
Table_open_cache_active_instances   1
Table_open_cache_hits           71892809
Table_open_cache_misses         50381
Table_open_cache_overflows      10201
Threadpool_threads          4
Threads_cached  0
Threads_connected           12
Threads_created             504
Threads_running             9
Uptime                  116292
Uptime_since_flush_status       116292
```

**Edit to add information requested in the comments**

The master and slave have 16 gig of physical memory.

Slave Status:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show slave status\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                Slave_IO_State: Reconnecting after a failed master event read
                   Master_Host: 10.53.17.154
                   Master_User: replication_user
                   Master_Port: 3306
                 Connect_Retry: 60
               Master_Log_File: DWR_Master.000002
           Read_Master_Log_Pos: 213653980
                Relay_Log_File: DWR_Server-relay-bin.000004
                 Relay_Log_Pos: 114299355
         Relay_Master_Log_File: DWR_Master.000001
              Slave_IO_Running: Connecting
             Slave_SQL_Running: No
               Replicate_Do_DB:
           Replicate_Ignore_DB: cronos,mysql,phpmyadmin,test
            Replicate_Do_Table:
        Replicate_Ignore_Table:
       Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
   Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                    Last_Errno: 1133
                    Last_Error: Error 'Can't find any matching row in the user table' on query. Default database: ''. Query: 'GRANT SELECT, SHOW VIEW, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES  ON `gistables`.* TO 'cuaeditlite'@'10.%''
                  Skip_Counter: 0
           Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 302102356
               Relay_Log_Space: 608187864
               Until_Condition: None
                Until_Log_File:
                 Until_Log_Pos: 0
            Master_SSL_Allowed: No
            Master_SSL_CA_File:
            Master_SSL_CA_Path:
               Master_SSL_Cert:
             Master_SSL_Cipher:
                Master_SSL_Key:
         Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
 Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                 Last_IO_Errno: 2003
                 Last_IO_Error: error reconnecting to master 'replication_user@10.53.17.154:3306' - retry-time: 60  maximum-retries: 86400  message: Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.53.17.154' (10060 "Unknown error")
                Last_SQL_Errno: 1133
                Last_SQL_Error: Error 'Can't find any matching row in the user table' on query. Default database: ''. Query: 'GRANT SELECT, SHOW VIEW, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES  ON `gistables`.* TO 'cuaeditlite'@'10.%''
   Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
              Master_Server_Id: 50
                Master_SSL_Crl:
            Master_SSL_Crlpath:
                    Using_Gtid: No
                   Gtid_IO_Pos:
       Replicate_Do_Domain_Ids:
   Replicate_Ignore_Domain_Ids:
                 Parallel_Mode: conservative
                     SQL_Delay: 0
           SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
       Slave_SQL_Running_State:
              Slave_DDL_Groups: 29
Slave_Non_Transactional_Groups: 1030778
    Slave_Transactional_Groups: 324
```

Change master statement:

```
CHANGE MASTER TO
  MASTER_HOST='10.53.17.154',
  MASTER_USER='replication_user',
  MASTER_PASSWORD='replication_password',
  MASTER_PORT=3306,
  MASTER_USE_GTID=slave_pos,
  MASTER_CONNECT_RETRY=60;
```

Settings from the post Rick linked to:

```
show variables like '%packet%';

| max_allowed_packet       | 16777216   |
| slave_max_allowed_packet | 1073741824 |

show variables like 'net_read_timeout';

| net_read_timeout | 30    |

show variables like 'slave_net_timeout';

| slave_net_timeout | 60    |

show variables like 'read_buffer_size';

| read_buffer_size | 131072 |
```

I should note that the size of the `max allowed packet size` on the slave does not match the master. The master `max allowed packet size` is currently set to 805306368.

Comment: What was the nature of the "outage that had us down for 4 days"? Did you have to reinstall MariaDB?

Comment: The data directory was accidentally deleted. MariaDB was, essentially, reinstalled.

Comment: The contents of the data directory were restored and although we have a few corrupt tables almost everything was recovered. Checks and repairs were made against all databases before dumping them to copy over to the slave.

Comment: Since the binlog position seems to be moving up, based on the logs you've posted, and the master complains about being unable to write to a socket every  minute or so, I'm inclined to think that the problem is in the network, despite what your network support folks might think. May be they want to run `tcpdump` and see what's going on in the replication session between "Slave: connected to master" and master's "Aborted connection".

Comment: How much RAM in each?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW SLAVE STATUS;`

Comment: Show us the `CHANGE MASTER ...` you used to start replication.  (Mask out the password.)

Comment: See if this helps: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/error-lost-connection.html

Comment: What are the values of net_read_timeout  and connect_timeout ?

Comment: Check the settings mentioned here:  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/229581/error-reading-packet-from-server-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-during-query

Comment: Thanks for looking @RickJames. Everything you asked for has been added to the question. The thing that jumps out to me is the difference in the `max_allowed_packet` between the slave and the master.

Comment: Thanks for the additional observation/comment @mustaccio. I too thought it smelled a lot like a network issue but connectivity to the box from elsewhere on the network is flawless. I'll keep using `tcpdump` in my back pocket though just in case. I'm hoping it's just some really stupid/dumb setting that I have incorrect.

Comment: `MASTER_USE_GTID=slave_pos` -- wouldn't the slave position be wrong after you restored it anew?

Comment: It shouldn't be since it was a fresh start/new slave and it was the first time replication had been started.

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
From MASTER and SLAVE, please
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis.